# Retrieve information for One to Many Mapping in JDBC

Tags: sql, jdbc

(** Ignore Case sensitivity**)

Below is my parent table

```
    Parent Table

    ID        name        name_id
   1001        A           1
   1002        B           2
   1003       AA           3

   Child Table

   Payment Table

   ID        PaymentName    name_id
   1         Credit           3
   2         Debit            3
```

Output is

```
   paymentName          name          name_id
     Credit              AA              3
     Debit               AA              3
```

In My Java

Parent POJO is

```
   int nameID;
   String name;

   List<Payment> paymentNames = new ArrayList<Payment>();
```

After JDBC call

```
while (resultSet.next()) {                     parent.setNameID(resultSet.getInt("name_ID"));
            parent.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));

  }
```

My Question is how do I retrieve the list of paymentNames??

Comment: What does the SQL look like? Are you joining those two tables?

Comment: SELECT parent.name, parent.name_id,payment.paymentName
    FROM parent 
    JOIN payment
    ON  parent.name_id = payment.name_id
    WHERE parent.name_id='3'
    WHERE approval_path.APPROVAL_PATH_ID ='2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed.

Created List

```
   Payment payment;
   List<Payment> paymentList = new ArrayList<Payment>();
```

Updated while loop

```
   while(resultset.next())
   {
   payment = new Payment();
   parent.setNameID(resultSet.getInt("name_ID"));
   parent.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
   payment.setPaymentName(resultSet.getString("paymentName");
   paymentList.add(payment);
   }
   parent.setPaymentNames (paymentList)
```